# Number of available processors in Python

Tags: java, python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In Java, this will return the number of available processors:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

This is handy when deciding how many long running threads to create.

Is there an equivalent function to call in Python?

Comment: Ack! I was looking through stackoverflow for days trying to find that. I was finding it hard to believe that no one had asked this already. Thank you Ruturaj!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, there are definitely duplicate answers out there

```
import os
os.cpu_count()
```

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.6 or greater ,

```
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```